# How to run python project in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a low-end PC and it takes ages to execute my python project  which takes much less time when running on Google Colab. So, is there a way to run this project in google-Colab.
My project :
[image]

I want to excute this project with this comands like in the terminal:
python -m minihit --help

python -m minihit input.txt

python -m minihit input.txt --render

python -m minihit input.txt --render --outprefix=/path/to/your/minimal_hitting_sets

python -m minihit input.txt --prune

python -m minihit input.txt --sort --render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly upload your .py files to google colab
or you can mount the google drive on your google colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

When you run, upper code, the authorization page is opened and you need to allow it.

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/
```

After sync with your drive, and import your file:

```
import minihit
```

you can reach your project with "!" character.

```
!python -m minihit --help
!python -m minihit input.txt
!python -m minihit input.txt --render
!python -m minihit input.txt --render --outprefix=/path/to/your/minimal_hitting_sets
!python -m minihit input.txt --prune
!python -m minihit input.txt --sort --render
```

I recommend that this colab will help you a lot:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qC2abKAIAlUM_jNAokGlooKY-idbSxi#scrollTo=X9_OYgn8Cots

Comment: thank you sir for your help but when i import minihit i get this error 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'minihit' @Mehmet Cagri Aksoy

Comment: name can be changed with the file name, can you follow the info :https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qC2abKAIAlUM_jNAokGlooKY-idbSxi#scrollTo=X9_OYgn8Cots

Comment: thank you sir so much you save my day @Mehmet Cagri Aksoy